# Error in Celery: TypeError("can_read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'",)

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to integrate celery to my django application.

I am following the tutorial provided here [Real Python : Asynchronous Tasks](https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/)

When I try to execute the following code:

```
 celery -A app_name worker -l info
```

I get the error:

```
[2017-07-12 22:43:16,118: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: 

TypeError("can_read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 594, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 88, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 345, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1039, in on_readable
    self.cycle.on_readable(fileno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 337, in on_readable
    chan.handlers[type]()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 671, in _receive
    while c.connection.can_read(timeout=0):
TypeError: can_read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

I am using celery version v4.0.2

What is the reason behind the error and how do I solve it?

Comment: If you are using redis server, upgrade it to redis-2.10.5. Since redis 2.10.5 is required by the celery

Comment: yup it worked. thanks.

Comment: Oh good then! Would be great if you could upvote my comment!